# Add UDID on site using TestFlight

Tags: testflight

I use **TestFlight** ([link](http://testflightapp.com)) for delivery .ipa files. My question is - how to add my UDID to my team?
Currently when I go to **People** and open my **User Details** the UDID field is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please if you need add devices use this link below:

[TestFlight add UDID](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829600-how-do-i-connect-my-device-to-my-account-)

Comment: Link appears to be broken.

Comment: Do not post a link without giving a quick summary of the content.

Comment: @Lobo seems link content was changed by owner

Comment: @Lobo Please remove down vote, because I can't handle test flight content and web pages. So when I posted this answer the link was appropriated. Please check also the link right now I have found a new url for you. Hope it will be helpful for you.